# How to inherit maven dependencies from parent to another parent?

Tags: java, maven, parent-child

I have problems with managing inherited dependencies. I have , at the top of the level, my "top" level project, with its own pom.xml which has

```
<dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <!-- Utils -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                <version>4.11</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

On the other side, I have my "second level" project which inherits the top project and I want to inherit junit dependency so:

```
    <parent>
        <artifactId>com.test</artifactId>
        <groupId>top-level-class</groupId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

<dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <!-- Utils -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

But this is catching dependency version. It says "The managed version could not be determinated, the artifact is managed in com.test.second-level-test:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"

Does anybody have any idea about how to fix this? Regards

Comment: just remove it out of the childs pom...

Comment: Have you declared the "second level" project as a module of the parent?

Comment: i put it as <dependencyManagement> because i want these dependency to be inheritage to another suns projects.

Comment: Yes, i have already declared second level project as a module of the parent

Comment: I deleted the dependency from second level class and i implemented that directly inside the child and it worked. Thanks all of you!

Answer (score 4):

Your 2nd level pom should look like this (dependencies should be directly under project):

```
        <project blabla>
    <parent>
        <artifactId>com.test</artifactId>
        <groupId>top-level-class</groupId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

     ....

        <dependencies>
            <!-- Utils -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
     ...

  </project>
```

Comment: but by this way, suns of this project will not inherit junit dependency, are they?